# BItcoind/P2Pool What am I doing wrong?

Tags: p2pool

I am running latest bitcoind and p2pool releases (default port settings) on Fedora 21 with ports open for 3332-3333, 8332-8333, and 9332-9333.  Everything appears to be well when connecting to the BC net, but when one of my miners (Antminer S5) connects to http://myhostname/IP port 3333 p2pool will not respond.  When I try to connect with port http://myhostname/IP port 9333, I get a twisted error complaining about authentication, but when I try to connect to port myhostname/IP (stratum+tcp??) port 9333 it looks like the miner is trying to connect and get work, but after several seconds p2pool reports a "handshake timeout" for the miner IP address.

This is the error I get:

```
2015-02-25 18:05:35.107254 Got peer connection from: IPv4Address(TCP, '192.168.0.21', 45024)
2015-02-25 18:05:45.108525 Handshake timed out, disconnecting from 192.168.0.21:45024
2015-02-25 18:05:45.109817 Peer connection lost: ('192.168.0.21', 45024) [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class  twisted.internet.error.ConnectionAborted'>: Connection was aborted locally, using.
2015-02-25 18:05:45.110143
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post any errors exactly how it looks on your computer? Also, stratum+tcp is generally going to be more reliable.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.  I chewed through things a little bit further and discovered that I needed to set the miner to port 9993.  But now it looks like my connection to the miner is getting dropped.

Comment: 2015-02-25 18:05:35.107254 Got peer connection from: IPv4Address(TCP, '192.168.0.21', 45024)                            2015-02-25 18:05:45.108525 Handshake timed out, disconnecting from 192.168.0.21:45024
2015-02-25 18:05:45.109817 Peer connection lost: ('192.168.0.21', 45024) [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.Connecti
onAborted'>: Connection was aborted locally, using.
2015-02-25 18:05:45.110143 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone! Got the p2pool server running last night.  Ended up recompiling a clean cloned Git of p2pool from foresttv (instead of the one on Bitmain), connected all miners to port 9332, and Voila!  One happy p2pool node!!

Answer (score 0):

The p2pool node communicates on more than one port. By default, miners connect to the node on port **9332** and other p2pool nodes ("peers") connect on port 9333.

So just switch your miner to port **9332**, that should fix your issue.